# How to put my web site online

Tags: web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I've developed a web site using symfony and wamp server on my pc and now I'd like to make it accessible to everyone on the web.

So what I'd like to know is the best host provider and domain register considering that it's a symfony project.

It's my first time launching a web site so I don't really know if I can have `ssh` access to the server host considering that it would be better than only dumping through ftp. Subversion is also important to quick updates.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/288107/how-to-put-my-web-site-online

Comment: Arg. I flagged it for moderator attention over there. This site is probably the best fit for it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no best host or registrar for a website built with Symfony. The registrar only affects your domain name and has nothing to do with the content of your website. And the hosting only needs to support PHP for Symfony to work. The vast majority of web hosts offer PHP. All you really need to do is verify they offer SSH (most do).

Instead of turning this into yet another web host and registrar recommendation thread I'm going to recommend you do some of your own research using the search functionality of this site and Google. That information is easy to find.